# Hyperparameter optimization for CNN

Tags: classification, optimization, hyperparameter

I have a database of defect images on materials, like holes, cuts, and so on. There is not so much information inside the images, I am aware of it.

I am using a CNN, in particular a ResNet50. I know it is too large for the type of data, but I have to respect the specifications that have been given to me.

I need to optimize hyperparameters like the number of epochs and the batch size. In the beginning, I was using train/validation/test split and performing the classical Early Stopping on the training + validation step. Then, I have opted for the Cross Validation.

In the end, now I am using the SHERPA library with the ASHA algorithm to optimize the number of epochs, the learning rate, and the batch size. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are not. Actually, unless we have access to a cluster that can train things independently (saying having 4+ GPUs) using something "simple" as Bayesian Optimisation would give us similar results on a "single big machine" with one chunky GPU. (Mostly because we won't be able to parallelise the training further) Ultimately, if our standard grid-search is correctly specified/implemented we should get qualitatively similar results.